# Concatenate multiple cells in a column into one cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need to combine multiple cells in a column in one cell.

Data is present in Column A:

```
0100
0800
ABCD
LMKQ
.
.
.
```

and so on

Cell B2 should have the below value:

'0100', '0800', 'ABCD', 'LMKQ'.... and so on

My code identifies all the data but populates just the data in last cell:

```
Sub concatMyData()

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(2, "B").Value = "'" & Cells(i, "A").Value & " '" & Cells(i + 1, "A").Value & "'"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If you have Excel 2016 you can use `TEXTJOIN`. The following formula in `B2` should do the job: `=CONCATENATE("'",TEXTJOIN("', '",TRUE,A2:A30),"'")`

Comment: I know excel formula.. but I need VBA code.. need to run it as part of a bigger script..

Comment: OK, I have removed the "Excel Formula" tag from your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
Sub concatMyData()
    Dim first As Boolean
    first = True
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Not first Then Cells(2, "B").Value = Cells(2, "B").Value & ", "
        Cells(2, "B").Value = Cells(2, "B").Value & "'" & Cells(i, "A").Value & "'"
        first = False
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Whilst this works, it's very inefficient, not only are you looping but you are posting over and over again to the sheet. See below code for how to do it without looping or if you insist on using a loop at least build a string variable instead of updating the sheet over and over then after the loop post the variable to the sheet. The way you have done this, if you have a load of calculations on the sheet It will calculate all the formulas every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one line of code and not have to loop (much MUCH faster):

```
Range("B2").Formula = "'" & join(application.transpose(Range("A2:A" & range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row)),"', '") & "'"
```

I assumed you have a header in A1 so started on A2, you can change it to A1 if you wish.

I noticed you asked for an explanation on the other answer so:

Egan's code will loop through each cell in column A and add it to what is currently in cell B2. So it basically adds to B2 the value of what cell it is up in in column A and a `', '`each time it loops until it runs out of data in column A. It also puts a `'` on the start and end.

My code will take the range and transpose it into an array (the data goes down, an array goes sideways so we transpose it), then it will join the array of values into a single string. We do this using the `JOIN` function and we specify `', '` as what it should put between each element of the array (the delimiter).

Then we simply add a `'` on the start and the end as it won't have it there to begin with and voila, one string of joined values without looping.

They effectively do the same thing, mine just does it in one go rather than a cell at a time.

Comment: Hello Dan, This code doesn't work.I get the output as :0110, 0800, CREA, TSMS, 2005
But I need: '0110', '0800', 'CREA', 'TSMS', '2005'